# how to display iframe with colorbox

Tags: jquery, html, colorbox

How to display iframe with colorbox. I tried following.

```
$.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#html_content", onLoad:function(){
alert("Colorbox Loaded")
}});

<body class="html_body" id="html_content_body">
<div id="html_content">
<form id="ajaxadd" action="/patient_add/" method="post" name="FormName" class="prettyform">
{% csrf_token %}

<table id="table_one" width="448" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
....
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you currently have any code?

Comment: please be more specific in your question and provide code if possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By looking at your code, I think you are not putting the scripts right. I must be like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css"/>
<script>
    $(function ()
    {
        $(".example6").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});    
    })
</script>
<a class='example6' href="http://google.com">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a>
```

On Firefox

[image: On Firefox]

On chrome
[image]

Comment: I have follwed that approach the href="" approach runs good but my orignal <body> </body> stuff showing in background as well as in lightbox cause of that reason (multiple Ids) my jquery datetimepicker stops working beacause they are running background.. according to my above code..

Comment: @GoldenBird are you using colorbox or light box? could you give me link, and also try to format your code.

Comment: @experimentX you are true, but you know your colorbox is not opening in middle of browser window. How it can be resolved. Thanx for response.

Comment: @GoldenBird well, i think you forgot to css or something, besides, please check the option in their site.

Comment: Yeah! i forgot the css. Thanks